# Normal Distribution Worded Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

[image]

- Standard deviation = 2.5 mL
- 98% of bottles must be between 998 mL and 1000mL
- Pr( 998 < x < 1000) = 0.98

This is a technology exam question, therefore to find the mean I used the method:

Solve(normCDF(998,1000,m,2.5)=0.98,m) but this results in an error

Is my working out wrong? Ignore the calculator syntax, but please refer to my understanding of the question, and what it is asking for.

Comment: I think you must standardize first. Subtract 998 and 1000 from the mean and divide by the standard deviation:

$0.98 = P(\frac{998-mean}{std dev} < Z < \frac{1000-mean}{std dev})$ where Z is Normal $(0,1)$.

Then use $P(a < Z < b) = P(Z < b) - P(Z < a)$.

Hmmm...not sure about this usually I have something like $0.98 = P(X < 0.6) = P(Z < \frac{0.6-mean}{std dev} = z)$ then I find the z on the distribution table/in Excel and then solve for mean.

Maybe someone else can follow up on this. Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve(normCDF(998,1000,m,2.5)=0.98,m)
```

I don´t have the 1000.

I have $P(X > 998 )=1-P(X\leq 998)=1-\Phi \left( \frac{998-\mu}{2.5} \right) = 0.98$

$\Phi(.)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

> •98% of bottles must be between 998 mL and 1000mL

No, 98% of the bottles must be above 998 ml.

Comment: Are you sure? The bottle contains at most 1 liter...

Comment: @BCLC What do you mean by "The bottle contains at most 1 liter..." ?

Comment: Calculus, the problem says that the bottle contains at most 1 L. But your solution removes the part 1000>x. Are you sure about doing such?

Comment: @BCLC The bottles contained at most 1 L before the machine is has been adjusted. With the new target the bottles doesn´t contain at most 1 L. By the way it is $P(X=k)=P(X=1000)=0$, because the normal distribution is continously.

Comment: OOOOOHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH